# Is there something like nodemon in Rust?

Tags: rust, wasm-pack

In javascript `nodemon` is a static files server that reloads on code changes.
I am using `wasm-pack` and `miniserve` to do two commands:

`build`

```
wasm-pack build --target web --out-name wasm --out-dir ./static/build
```

`serve`:

```
miniserve ./static --index index.html
```

I would love these two to be automated just like in javascript with `nodemon`.

Comment: [cargo watch](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-watch) is what you want

Answer (score 4):

Use [cargo-watch](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-watch) and pass shell commands to execute using `-s` or `--shell`  flags:

```
cargo watch -s 'wasm-pack build --target web --out-name wasm --out-dir ./static/build && miniserve ./static --index index.html'
```

Thanks for the help [Lux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458413/lux) and [kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189130/kmdreko)

Answer (score 0):

Use [chobs](https://crates.io/crates/chobs). It can execute your command and restart it on changes.

```
chobs watch -e "crago run -- -f -e -b"
```

or any other exec.